How to scroll a widget to only partially visible at the bottom or fully visible at the top as shown in these two images?
I am trying to implement a scrolling behavior in my Flutter application where a widget can be scrolled to either be only partially visible at the bottom of the screen or fully visible at the top. I've attached two images to illustrate the desired outcomes:


You can use AnimatedPositioned widget instead of Positioned , add a boolean isOpen for example , and give AnimatedPositioned two cases in the bottom parameter  , isOpen ? 120 : 20 , for Example :
AnimatedPositioned(
    bottom: isOpened ? 120 : 20,
    duration : Duration(milliseconds : 300),
    child : [your widget],
    ),

If have any question don't hesitate to ask.

HeIpful, i used your approach, but i  changed AnimatedPositionned  to AnimatedSize, since my widget was already positionned at the bottom.  Works fine known.

You can use DraggableScrollableSheet

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.black12, width: double.infinity),
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.1,
            minChildSize: 0.1,
            builder: (_, scrollController) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  itemCount: 25,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item $index'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

